# Sanitizing request URI in Spring Cloud Gateway

Tags: spring-cloud-gateway

I want to sanitize part of the uri when using Spring Cloud Gateway.

For example: http://localhost:8080//login.

In this example I want to remove double slash with single slash even before Spring Gateway tries to find a suitable route for this request.

Using Global filter is the right approach? Or is there any other hook that can be leveraged to intercept the request and modify the uri?

Answer (score 0):

I created a filter class that implements `org.springframework.web.server.WebFilter` and registered it as the Spring bean.

Now this filter get's called even before Spring Gateway tries to match a route. This way I was able to sanitize the request URI. I looked at `RewritePathGatewayFilterFactory` for inspiration.